# Is there any way to wait for dynamic content to be added after page.click() in puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, cheerio

I have been writing a code which scrapes the [Trailblazer](https://trailblazer.me/id/hverma99) site.
The website is a **dynamic** one, So when i click the **Show More** button it loads the other badges owned the user. So is there a way for me to click that button and then wait for the new content to be added before loading the markup in cheerio for scraping.

Currently i am just making the broswer wait for 3 seconds before re-click but it makes the whole process take a lot of time and it may also fail if the browser fails to fetch in that time.

So is there any alternative to this?
Please find my code below -->

```
    const url = "https://trailblazer.me/id/akganesa";

  // function to load the page
    async function getPage() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});

    const [first_button] = await page.$x("//button[contains(., 'Show More')]");
    await first_button.click();
    while (
      (await (await page.$x("//button[contains(., 'Show More')]")).length) > 0
    ) {
      const [button] = await page.$x("//button[contains(., 'Show More')]");
      await button.click();
      await page.waitForResponse(response => response.status() === 200);
    }

    const html = await page.content(); // serialized HTML of page DOM.
    await browser.close();
    return html;
  }

      // using cheerio to scrape
      const html = await getPage();
      const $ = cheerio.load(html);
```

Comment: does clicking button generate network requests? if yes, try using [`waitForResponse`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v2.1.1/docs/api.md#pagewaitforresponseurlorpredicate-options)

Comment: Did you try waitForSelector?

Comment: @hardkoded and mbit Yes, i did try. I also tried the waitForNavigation but both of them returned a timeout error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code below works for what you're asking. The reason I have it click [first_button] before entering the while loop is that the first "show more" button doesn't actually make a network request.

```
const go = async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    args: [
      "--no-sandbox",
      "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
      "--window-size=1600,1200"
    ],
    defaultViewport: null
  });
  const context = await browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext();
  const page = await context.newPage();
  try {
    await page.goto("https://trailblazer.me/id/akganesa", {
      waitUntil: "networkidle2"
    });
    const [first_button] = await page.$x("//button[contains(., 'Show More')]");
    await first_button.click();
    while (
      (await (await page.$x("//button[contains(., 'Show More')]")).length) > 0
    ) {
      const [button] = await page.$x("//button[contains(., 'Show More')]");
      await button.click();
      await page.waitForResponse(response => response.status() === 200);
    }
    browser.close();
    return;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    browser.close();
    return;
  }
};

go();
```

Comment: 1 --> I have updated the above code to match your provided answer but this code only returns the html after one **Show More**. 

2 -->Your answer works fine however it does not **return the page.content** after all the loading is done and i need it to proceed to my required task.
So can you help me fix either of the solution

Comment: nvm i got it figured out

Comment: However do let me know how to return page.content from your code as I failed to do so.

Comment: @Maverick ```const html = await page.content()``` before the browser.close() and then pass ```html``` into your cheerio function. If you're returning html from the function, make sure that the function that is getting your html and doing something to it is marked async and is awaiting the result of the function ```go()``` before it does anything with it.